# How to turn an array into a map in PHP?

Tags: php

This is based on a previous question I asked.
Lets say I have run an SQL query and received the following into a variable `$res`:

```
name    |    language
-------------------------
bob     |   English
bob     |   Dutch
Sally   |   English
Sally   |   Spanish
Sally   |   German
```

i.e. `$res["name"]` currently equals the first column etc.

Is there a PHP function or sequence of functions (without writing a loop) to turn `$res` into a map so that I could write `$res["bob"]` and receive an array `["English", "Dutch"]` or `$res["Sally"]` and receive `["English", "Spanish", "German"]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$map = array();
foreach ($mysqlResult as $row) {
    $map[$row['name']][] = $row['language'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I specified that I didnt want to use a loop. See the selected answer for what I meant.

Comment: @twerdster You *did* specify that you wanted a PHP function though. There's also nothing wrong with using a loop here, it's the most straight forward answer.

Comment: Good point. Il give you the points. Luckily someone else was able to see through my bad question style and answer my actual question.

Answer (score 1):

If there were a native function, it would use a loop internally anyway.

```
$res = array();
foreach($old as $value) {
   $res[$value['name']][] = $value['language'];
}
```

**Edit**: I see this is a one to many relationship :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with mysql using group by :

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php

Comment: Brilliant! Youre the only one who has been able to point me in the right direction over 3 different posts on this topic :) The command I was looking for was GROUP_CAT. Found it here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `array_reduce`:

```
$rows = array_from_sql_query();

$map = array_reduce($rows, function($res, $row) {
  $res[$row['name']][] = $row['language'];
  return $res;
}, []);
```